# Do all other desktop and mobile browsers support application/xhtml+xml except IE's all version till 8 and IE mobile?

Tags: xhtml, cross-browser, mime

Do all other desktop and mobile browsers support content served as `application/xhtml+xml` except IE's all version till 8 and IE mobile?

Comment: what do you really want to ask?

Comment: I found my answer here http://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/xhtml/media-types/results

Comment: Good find. Worth adding that (I believe) IE 8 doesn’t support content served as `application/xhtml+xml` either.

Answer (score 0):

There's something extra to say about mobile devices and content served as `application/xhtml+xml`. According to [these tests](http://simon.html5.org/articles/mobile-results) by Simon Pieters, only Opera Mini handles XHTML correctly. All other browsers "eat everything as tag soup".